# Why won't google Chrome dev tools see outer context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging

In previous browser versions I didn't have such a problem, but now dev-tools doesn't see outer context of function:

[image]

Maybe it is optional and I can turn on outer context visibility?